# Cent Os 7 How to add 8 Tera unallocated /dev/sda memory to Disk Space (dev/mapper)

Tags: hard-drive

I have searched and viewed multiple guides but none of them work on my case. I have a CentOs7 Raid 1 (
server bought online and therefore not physically in my hand) and I have completely filled the memory of my webserver. I would like to add the 8 terabyte HDD (it is already inside but not used) and be able to upload all my data. How can I do? The hdd has never been formatted or partitioned.

I bought a webserver from a third party and can only access it via bash but not ask for support.
Thanks

I have seen many guides but none of them I can complete because no one is in my condition

Here if i pressed on bash fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512.1 GB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000f3a17

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/nvme0n1p1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme0n1p2         2099200  1000214527   499057664   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00079732

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/nvme1n1p1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme1n1p2         2099200   976773119   487336960   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 1071 MB, 1071644672 bytes, 2093056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 498.9 GB, 498897780736 bytes, 974409728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 8001.6 GB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 959A27A5-409A-4C7A-9E35-A511C12703C2


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name

Disk /dev/mapper/Volume00-root: 450.9 GB, 450887680000 bytes, 880640000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/Volume00-swap: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/Volume00-tmp: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

And here if i pressed of bash df -h

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                    16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       16G  393M   16G   3% /run
tmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/Volume00-root  414G  393G  167M 100% /
/dev/mapper/Volume00-tmp   3.9G   17M  3.6G   1% /tmp
/dev/md0                   990M  152M  772M  17% /boot
tmpfs                      3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```